# Wrong relation condition While querying Laravel Many to many Relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

## Table and Model

I have a question. So first, let me explain the tables involved in my question along with their models.

1. Project

```
// Table Migration
Schema::create('project', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('kode_proyek')->primary(); // Ubah menjadi primary key
            $table->string('nama_proyek');
            $table->string('client');
            $table->string('lokasi');
            $table->string('pekerjaan');
            $table->string('status');
            $table->foreignId('vendor_id')->nullable()->default(null)->constrained('vendor')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->double('budget_rab')->nullable()->default(null);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

// Table Relationship Model
    public function vendor() {
        return $this->hasOne(Vendor::class, 'vendor_id');
    }

    public function detailPekerjaan() {
        return $this->hasMany(DetailPekerjaan::class, 'kode_proyek', 'kode_proyek');
    }

    public function projectCashflow() {
        return $this->hasMany(ProjectCashflow::class, 'kode_proyek', 'kode_proyek');
    }
```

2. Vendor

```
// Migration
Schema::create('vendor', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id(); // Primary key
            $table->string('nama_vendor');
            $table->timestamps(); // Kolom created_at dan updated_at
        });
// Relation
    public function detailPekerjaan() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(DetailPekerjaan::class, 'pekerjaan_vendor_rab', 'vendor_id', 'detail_pekerjaan_id')->withPivot('rab_item_id');
    }
```

3. Detail Pekerjaan

```
// Tables
Schema::create('detail_pekerjaan', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('kode_proyek');
            $table->string('item');
            $table->string('ukuran');
            $table->string('keterangan');
            $table->decimal('harga_penawaran', 10, 2);
            $table->timestamps();

            // Definisi foreign key untuk kolom 'kode_proyek'
            $table->foreign('kode_proyek')->references('kode_proyek')->on('project')->onDelete('cascade');
        });

// Relation
public function proyek()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class, 'kode_proyek');
    }

    public function vendors() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Vendor::class, 'pekerjaan_vendor_rab', 'detail_pekerjaan_id', 'vendor_id')->withPivot('rab_item_id');
    }
```

4. Rab Item

```
// Table
Schema::create('rab_item', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->json('data');
            $table->integer('subtotal_material')->nullable()->default(0);
            $table->integer('subtotal_ongkos_kerja')->nullable()->default(0);
            $table->integer('total_material_ongkos_kerja')->default(DB::raw('(subtotal_material + subtotal_ongkos_kerja)'));
            $table->decimal('lain_lain_percent', 5, 2)->nulable()->default(0);
            $table->decimal('jasa_kontraktor_percent', 5, 2)->nullable()->default(0);
            $table->integer('grand_total')->default(DB::raw('(
                total_material_ongkos_kerja + 
                (total_material_ongkos_kerja * (lain_lain_percent / 100)) + 
                (total_material_ongkos_kerja * (jasa_kontraktor_percent / 100))
            )'));
            $table->timestamps();
        });

// Relation
public function rabPivotItem() {
        return $this->belongsTo(RabPivotItem::class, 'rab_item_id');
    }
```

5. Pekerjaan Vendor Rab (Tables that connects detail_pekerjaan, vendor, and rab_item_id

```
Schema::create('pekerjaan_vendor_rab', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('detail_pekerjaan_id')->constrained('detail_pekerjaan')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('vendor_id')->constrained('vendor')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('rab_item_id')->nullable()->constrained('rab_item')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Currently, I have successfully added data to the "detail pekerjaan" table, and here is the process:

1. User input detail pekerjaan
2. When the input is successful, the data will be entered into the "detail pekerjaan" table.

```
$detailPekerjaan = DetailPekerjaan::create([
                    'kode_proyek' => $kode_project,
                    'item' => $item,
                    'ukuran' => $validated['ukuran'][$index],
                    'keterangan' => $validated['keterangan'][$index],
                    'harga_penawaran' => $validated['harga_penawaran'][$index],
                ]);
```

3. After successfully entering the data into the "detail pekerjaan" table, the data will also be entered into the "pekerjaan_vendor_rab" table and will be generated as many times as the number of vendors when the data is generated.

```
if ($detailPekerjaan) {
                    foreach ($vendorData as $vendor) {
                        $detailPekerjaan->vendors()->attach($vendor);
                    }

                    $successCount++;
                }
```

Example, currently there are 2 vendors: Vendor A with ID 1 and Vendor B with ID 2. And the user inputs Item1 with ID 1 into the "detail pekerjaan". The following will happen in the "pekerjaan_vendor_rab" table:

```
detail_pekerjaan_id  |  vendor_id  |  rab_item_id  |
      1              |      1      |      null     |
      1              |      2      |      null     |
```

Why null? Because I will use this value for my view. If it's null, it will display the ❌ icon. If there's a value, it will be represented by the ✅ icon.

## Things I Tried

What I'm currently trying to do is read the value from the `detail_pekerjaan.harga_penawaran` field with a condition `WHERE detail_pekerjaan.kode_proyek == $kodeProject` (`$kodeProject` coming from the route parameter) and divide it by `rab_item.grand_total` (assuming `rab_item_id` is not null). Here are the efforts that have been made:

```
// Controller
$projectData = Project::where('kode_proyek', $kode_project)->first();
        $detailPekerjaan = $projectData->detailPekerjaan;
        $vendors = Vendor::whereHas('detailPekerjaan', function ($query) use ($kode_project) {
            $query->where('kode_proyek', $kode_project);
        })
            ->with('detailPekerjaan')
            ->get();

        $groupedData = [];
        $vendorProfit = [];
        
        foreach ($vendors as $vendor) {
            $profitPercent = 0;
            $totalProfit = 0;

            foreach ($vendor->detailPekerjaan as $detail) {
                $groupedData[$vendor->id][$detail->id] = $detail->pivot->rab_item_id;

                $rabItemId = $groupedData[$vendor->id][$detail->id];
                $rabItem = RabItem::find($rabItemId); 
                
                if ($rabItem) {
                    // Hitung persentase dan profit
                    $percentage = round($detail->harga_penawaran / $rabItem->grand_total, 2); // Bulatkan ke 2 digit desimal
                    $profit = round($detail->harga_penawaran - $rabItem->grand_total, 2); // Bulatkan ke 2 digit desimal
        
                    $profitPercent += $percentage;
                    $totalProfit += $profit;
                }
            }

            $vendorProfit[$vendor->id] = [
                'percentage' => $profitPercent,
                'total' => $totalProfit,
            ];
        }
```

## The Question/ Problems

This is a summary generated from `profitPercent` and `totalProfit`, but the values are incorrect. Where is the issue? The issue is that the calculations are being performed without filtering whether the project details linked to the `rab_item` through the `pekerjaan_vendor_rab` table have `kode_proyek == $kodeProject`.
[Output Rightnow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nNq4.png)